# Папка пользователя в python, Как показать содержимое стандартных папок пользователя Windows на любом компьютере

Tags: python, проектирование

Как показать содержимое стандартных папок пользователя Windows на любом компьютере?

Я попытался создать что-то подобное с помощью `os.list.dir`. Но она работает только для определенной папки пользователя. А мне нужен универсал, то есть чтобы работал на любом компьютере с любым именем папки пользователя.

Вот код:

```
import os, sys
import os.path
import string

print(os.listdir('C:/myuser/Music/'))
```

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос пример, в каком виде Вы хотели бы получить вывод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Можно получить папку текущего юзера через [`os.getenv('USERPROFILE')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) пример:

```
import os

homepath = os.getenv('USERPROFILE')
print(homepath)  # C:\Users\MyUser

file_name = os.path.normpath(homepath + '/Music/')
print(file_name)  # C:\Users\MyUser\Music
```

##### Еще удобно работать через [Path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('~').expanduser()
print(path)  # C:\Users\MyUser

print(path / 'Music')  # C:\Users\MyUser\Music
```

Одним шагом:

```
print(Path('~/Music').expanduser())
# C:\Users\MyUser\Music
```

Answer (score 2):

Под универсальностью, нужно полагать, подразумевается некая "фиксированность" путей. Тогда лучше использовать WinAPI, конкретней - [SHGetFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw). Например:

```
from os     import listdir
from ctypes import create_unicode_buffer, windll

buf = create_unicode_buffer(260)
windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(None, 5, None, 0, buf)
print(listdir(buf.value))
```

Этот пример выведет список содержимого первого уровня папки *Documents* (в Windows XP, как помним, это будут *Мои документы*). Иными словами, получение пути по CLSID'у папки - идеологически верный путь.
Что касается использования переменных окружения - это заведомо не самый лучший в плане универсальности путь (почему - *см. выше*). Если даже заложиться на почку, дескать, переменные ни при каких обстоятельствах не будут удалены или изменены, то тогда проще сделать так:

```
from os      import listdir
from os.path import expanduser

print(listdir(expanduser(r'~\Documents')))
```

Comment: Мне кажется ваш пример с `print(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Music'))` нужно сначала показать, а после с winapi :)

Answer (score 1):

Имя (логин) пользователя храниятся в переменной окружения `USERNAME`. 
Строим путь до домашней папки:

```
homefolder = os.path.join("c:\\Users\\", os.environ['USERNAME'])
```

Итого:

```
print(os.listdir(homefolder))
```

Comment: Да почему ж не допускаю. Не только допускаю, но и сам так делал.